# Convert a Unix-based PHP script into a batch file for Windows

Tags: php, batch-file

I want to convert this PHP script which works great on a Unix system into a script for Windows.

I don't know how to rewrite it. Can someone help me?

Here is the script:

```
$cmd = 'nohup sudo -u '.$user.' bash -c "cd ' .
escapeshellarg($path) . '; VVERBOSE=true QUEUE=' .
escapeshellarg($queue) . ' APP_INCLUDE=' .
escapeshellarg($bootstrap_path) . ' INTERVAL=' .
escapeshellarg($interval) . ' CAKE=' .
escapeshellarg(CAKE) . ' COUNT=' . $count .
' php ./resque.php';
$cmd .= ' > '. escapeshellarg($log_path).' 2>&1" >/dev/null 2>&1 &';

passthru($cmd);
```

Comment: That's not a bash script! It looks more like perl or perhaps PHP.

Comment: Also, a better idea would be to describe what you want done (and what you have done so far to try to solve this yourself), instead of making us try to decode your script

Answer (score 2):

passthru is a method in PHP see http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php

Do you know what the script does? Maybe reverse engineer it into windows batch script?

From the looks of it, the script came from a *nix system it:

- execute a command as another user
- change the current directory
- set environment variables
- calls a PHP script directly from the PHP interpreter and dumps the log into a file, and pipes the stderrs to /dev/null

That script is imo, is impossible to "covert" to Windows batch script (since Windows != POSIX), you need to rewrite it.

Comment: Thanks Bill, its exactly what it does i know, this php script is used on an unix system that why it uses commands like sudo, bash, etc... i want to rewrite it but i really don't know how to do, could you help me or give me a way to learn how? Thanks

Comment: For starters the only commands that can't be ported over is the nohup (?) and the sudo in windows. The rest should be relatively easy.
- cd (linux), cd (windows)
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/110930 for redirecting stdout and err
- set (windows) for setting the variables. 
Why do you need to convert it to windows?

Comment: Because i'm working in local on windows. I just tried to get it worked with cygwin, i've deleted "nohup sudo" but it's still remaining an error. Here is the content of $cmd: bash -c "cd "D:\WebServer\www\MyProject\app\Plugin\Resque\Vendor\php-resque\"; VVERBOSE=true QUEUE="default" APP_INCLUDE="D:\WebServer\www\MyProject\app\Plugin\Resque\Lib\ResqueBootstrap.php" INTERVAL="5" CAKE="D:\WebServer\www\MyProject\lib\Cake\" COUNT=1 php ./resque.php > "D:\WebServer\www\MyProject\app\tmp\logs\php-resque-worker.log" 2>&1" >/dev/null 2>&1 &

Comment: And i get the following error: "The specified path was not found."